# Google Chrome - NETWORK_IP_ADDRESSES_CHANGED - pages only partially load

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome version (8.0.552.224 (Official Build 68599))

I have developed a web site using asp.net mvc and jquery. it uses a lot of ajax. 
I noticed that occasionally a web page does not complete loading all files from the server.

Browsing through forums It seems that this also happens to other people.
Looking in to the Chromium Net-Internals ( type: `chrome://net-internals/` as a url in the chrome browser ) I noticed that the pages do not complete loading if a `NETWORK_IP_ADDRESSES_CHANGED` event occurred.

Any files that were not fetched from the server before the time of the NETWORK_IP_ADDRESSES_CHANGED event failed to arrive with error (-3)

Do you know why the NETWORK_IP_ADDRESSES_CHANGED event occurs?
Is there a way to stop it from happening?

Thanks and be happy, Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been accepted by the Chromium team as a bug.

If you are interested to track its progress it can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68109)